# Store temp data per user Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating asp.net-mvc application where user is uploading multiple files. 
The data will be compared with db data, processed and exported later. Also paging.

When displaying these data, sorting and filtering is importing.

When data is uploaded, some of them will be stored in db, some will be displayed as not found in db, some will be modified and stored ... etc

My question is, what is the best way to store the uploaded data in order to be available to be process or viewed?

1. Load in memory
2. Create temp tables for every session? (even don't know if possible)
3. Different storage which can be queryable (access data using linq) (JSON??)
4. Another option.

The source files are (csv or excel)

One of the files example

```
Name    Age     Street    City     Country    Code    VIP
---------------------------------------------------------
Mike    42      AntwSt    Leuven   Belgium    T5Df    No
Peter   32      Ut123     Utricht  Netherland T666    Yes
```

Example of class

```
public class User
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Address Address { get; set; }   // street, city,country
     public Info Info { get; set; }         // Age, and Cres 
}

public class Info
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Cres Cres { get; set; }
}

public class Cres
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool VIP { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: What is the typical life cycle/use case of what you're doing? Are users simply uploading data and waiting for it to be processed? Or is something else occurring? You could look into server-side session state storage. Something like REDIS perhaps.

Comment: Yes, user is uploading data and wait for result, i will check REDIS will see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of strategies for handling this (I actually just wrote an entire dissertation over the subject), and there are many different considerations you'll need to take under consideration to achieve this.

Depending on the amount of data present, and what you're doing with it, it may be simple enough to simply store information in Session Storage. Now how you actually implement the session store is up to you, and there are [pros and cons](http://phillbarber.blogspot.com/2014/02/client-side-vs-server-side-session.html) to how you decide to do that.

I would personally recommend a server side session store to handle everything and there are a variety of different options for how to do that. For example: [SSDB](http://ssdb.io/) and [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Then from there, you'll need a way of communicating to clients what has actually happened with their data. If multiple clients need to access the same data set and a single user uploads a change, how will you alert every user of this change? Again, there are a lot of options, you can use a [Pub/Sub Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254(v=vs.110).aspx) to alert all listening clients. You could also tap into Microsoft's [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) framework to attempt to handle this.

There's a lot of different If's, But's, Maybe's, etc to the question, and unfortunately I don't believe there is any one perfect solution to you problem without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for taking the time answering my question!.
I checked Redis and it seems that i have to perform some setup on the server side. therefore i did some research to have some simple solution and found the following:
**System.Web.Caching** and **HTTPContext.Curent.Cache** and **HttpRunTime.Cache** and **System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache** . too many options, in my situation, what is the best one in your opinion, i just want to store the data for each user during the session

Comment: There's a many different options unfortunately. I would [check out this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/Asp-Net-framework-server-side-data-caching-techniques/). And get a feel for server side caching.

Answer (score 1):

If the data size is small and you just need them to exist temporarily, feel free to go with storing them in memory and thus cut all the overhead your would have with other solutions.

You just need to be sure to consider that the data in memory will be gone if the server or the app is switched off for whatever reason.

It might also be a good idea to consider, what happens if the same user performs the operation for the second time, while the operation on the first data is not completed yet. If this can happen to you (it usually does), make sure to use good synchronization mechanisms to prevent race conditions.